# Matrix multiplication by group

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I am doing multiplication of two matrices, saying betas and Xs. 
But my data has a group variable and I did the regression by group.
Here is a example what I am trying to do.

```
matx <- matrix(c(1,1,2,1,3,4,2,5,6,2,7,8,3,9,10,3,11,12),nrow=6,ncol=3,byrow=T)
colnames(matx) <- c("group","x1","x2")
b <- matrix(c(1,3,4,2,5,6,3,0,0),nrow=3,ncol=3,byrow=T)
colnames(b) <- c("group","b1","b2")
```

What I wanna do is multiplying `matx` and `b` by `group` variable.
x1 and x2 of group 1 should be multiplied by group 1's b1 b2.
Is there a any code that makes it easy instead of separating data by group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the `unique` values of 'group', subset both the matrices and do `%*%`

```
sapply(unique(matx[,'group']), function(i) 
          matx[matx[,1]==i,-1]%*% b[b[,1]==i, -1])
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   11   61    0
#[2,]   25   83    0
```